# How to join tables on incompatible columns?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have link to a timecard third party data file in Access and the field I am having problems with is listed as a "short-text" field. That field is a employee number which has all numeric data in it. When I link to the employee file to get the employee name I do not get a complete match on all records. I have used the keyword "Var" to convert the number but how do I use that number to link to the employee file? We have been converting the needed data in the two tables to numeric values and then using those tables but that is time consuming and defeats the purpose of data being current automatically. Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the conversion on the fly

```
SELECT *
FROM A, B
WHERE CLng(A.Id) = CLng(B.Id)
```

(I am assuming that the column in `A` is already numeric.)

You can do the conversion by using the join-syntax as well, but the query designer will not be able to display this query, if functions are used in the `ON` clause.

Comment: Column A.Id is alpha.

Comment: Then both have to be converted. It is not a good idea to store numeric data in text columns. This often done because the numbers have to be formatted in a specific way. But this formatting should be done in the UI, not in the DB! It would also be interesting to know why the tables are not joined correctly. Do the fields in the two tables have a different number of leading zeroes or leading and trailing spaces?

Comment: I agree but this is a third party software that I have no control over so I have to make due with their formatting.